# NASM: Implementing Mouse Functionality in Binary File using segments (implementing a boot loader)

Tags: nasm

I am trying to implement the mouse functionality in my  desktop application. I have successfully implemented the custom boot loader which transfers the control to the desktop application. The problem is that it cannot display the complete design i want to print. If anyone can help i will be thankful to you .. 
Another problem which i m facing is that i cannot use a "seg" command in binary file (.bin) . It gives us an error that flat binary does not allow segment base reference. If there is another way to load a custom segment (ES) register then please tell me. I want to do this to implement mouse code which i post below. This code is in a separate file. It only displays the background color . It does not display any character or number on screen.

Thanks in advance

```
bits 16
jmp main

left db "Left Mouse Button Pressed at Coordinates: ","$"
right db "Right Mouse Button Pressed at Coordinates: ","$"
move db "Mouse Moved at Coordinates: ","$"
next_line db 0DH,0AH, "$"
x_coord dw 0
y_coord dw 0
coord dw 0
;.code

main:
cli
mov ax,cs
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov ss, ax
sti

call clrrg ; Clear Data/General Registers

; Changing Video Mode as Per Requirement
mov ah,00h  ; Change Video Mode 
mov al,12h  ; AL=12h, Video Mode 640*480
int 10h

mov ah,0Bh
mov bh,0
mov bl,09h
int 10h

; Show Mouse Cursor on Screen
mov ax,2        ; show Mouse Cursor Functionj
int 33h         ; Mouse Interrupt
call clrrg      ; Clear Registers


mov dx,cs   ; Load Segment Address
mov es,dx           ; Store contents of dx in es
mov dx, [mouse_handler] ; Load Offset of Function (mouse_handler)
; Step # 02
.mloop:
mov cx, 00001011b ; CX=00001011b tells, we want to generate Interrupt
;                 if Left Mouse Button OR Right Mouse Button is Pressed
call mouse_handler
mov ax,000Ch    ; Setup Interrupt Vector Entry for Specific Mouse Event
int 33h         ; Call Mouse Interrupt

call clrrg      ; Clear Registers
jmp .mloop

mouse_handler:

;if ax==00000010b ; Means Left Mouse Button is Pressed
cmp ax, 2
jne .next
mov [x_coord],dx
mov [y_coord],cx
;mov dx,[left]  ; Print Message
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h
mov dx,word x_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print X Coordinates
mov al,","          ; Print Comma
mov ah,0eh
int 10h
mov dx,word y_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print Y Coordinates
;mov dx,[next_line] ; Print Next Line
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h

.next:
;if ax==00001000b ; Means Right Mouse Button is Pressed
cmp ax, 00001000b
jne .next1
mov [x_coord],dx
mov [y_coord],cx
;mov dx,[right] ; Print Message
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h
mov dx,word x_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print X Coordinates
mov al,","          ; Print Comma
mov ah,0eh
mov bx, 0
int 10h
mov dx,word y_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print Y Coordinates
;mov dx,[next_line] ; Print Next Line
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h

.next1:
;if ax==00000001b ; Means Mouse is Moved
cmp ax, 1
jne .next2
mov [x_coord],dx
mov [y_coord],cx
;mov dx,[move]  ; Print Message
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h
mov dx,word x_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print X Coordinates
mov al,","          ; Print Comma
mov ah,0eh
mov bh, 0
mov bl, 4
int 10h
mov dx,word y_coord
mov [coord], dx     ; Passing as Argument in Variable
call print_coord    ; Print Y Coordinates
;mov dx,[next_line] ; Print Next Line
;mov ah,09h
;int 21h
.next2:
ret

;*******************************
; Procedure to Print Coordinates
;*******************************
print_coord:
call clrrg          ; Clear Data Registers
mov ax,coord        ; Move "coord" in 'ax' (Numerator goes in ax)
mov bx,10           ; Move 10 in bx  (Denominator goes in bx)
; If value is ZERO
cmp ax, 0
jne .looping        
add al,48
mov ah,0eh
mov bx, 0
mov bl, 4
int 10h
jmp .return

; For Values other than ZERO
.looping:
mov dx,0
div bx
push dx
inc cx
cmp ax, 0
jne .looping
.p:
pop dx
add dl,48
mov al, dl
mov ah,0eh
mov bx, 0
mov bl, 4
int 10h
loop .p
.return:
ret

clrrg:
mov ax,0
mov bx,0
mov cx,0
mov dx,0
ret
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need "seg". If your address is constant you can simply use `mov ax, ADDRESS >> 4 
mov es, ax`or `mov ax, ADDRESS  shr ax, 4  mov es, ax`.